# CORS access blocking

Tags: javascript, php, http-headers, cors

I might need some help here.

I was trying to establish a connection with `XMLHttpRequest` from JavaScript to a PHP Script on another origin.

First thing I noticed was that I got a error from this request which told me that there were header missing. I searched a bit and found [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). I modified the header like this:

JS

```
//this.mozSystem = true;
this.open("POST", url, true);
this.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
this.setRequestHeader("ADDON-TO-SERVER", "");
this.setRequestHeader("Content-length", massage.length);
this.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

PHP

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Request-Method: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ADDON-TO-SERVER,Content-type");
```

And it works ... but I am not sure why in

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ADDON-TO-SERVER,Content-type");`

`Content-type` is needed.

Mozilla told me to add this one, but I though that it would just need one custom header, and isn't `Content-type` a basic one ?

Could someone tell me why this is needed and tell me if I done everything like it is intended to.

Thanks for any help,
Feirell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as headers go in the context of CORS, a `Content-type` request header with the value of `application/json` is not considered a “basic one” (to borrow your wording).

In the context of CORS, a `Content-type` request header is only considered “basic” if its value is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`.

So your browser will allow a `Content-type: application/json` request from your Web application to work as expected only if the server you are sending that request to explicitly indicates that it’s OK with receiving such requests. And the way a server does that is by responding with a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`header that contains `Content-type`.

The rationale for your browser enforcing that restriction is that unless a server explicitly indicates is it OK with certain kinds of cross-origin requests, CORS is not intended to allow Web applications to do any kind of programmatic cross-origin requests that do anything more than what a basic HTML `form`-element action have always been able to do cross-origin.

And so since before CORS came along, HTML page have always been restricted just to sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` requests cross-origin, that’s what the basic CORS behavior is restricted to unless the server opts-in for more.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense, so I have to list any other header which is not normal, so the server even considers the request ? Your addition with the original behavior for forms makes this even better to understand, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, basically if you add any custom headers to your request—beyond the headers your browser sends on its own—it will only work if the server you’re requesting from indicates it’s OK with getting those request headers.